# Connect On Premise Gateway to On Premise Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, power-automate

I am using Power Automate. Now I want to access our on premise Azure DevOps Data.

I found this Question ([ower Automate with Azure Devops Server (On Premis...](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Connecting-To-Data/Power-Automate-with-Azure-Devops-Server-On-Premise/td-p/658618))

And installed a On Premise Gateway. ([Manage an on-premises data gateway in Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/gateway-manage))

Now I am able to see it in my Power Automate Data Tab.

But I have no idea how to connect my On Premise Gateway to my On Premise Azure DevOps?

Comment: Two years have passed. @Peter: did you solve this by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to connect my On Premise Gateway to my On Premise Azure DevOps?

You need to connect to on-premises Azure DevOps over Http with Azure AD. That means you need to create a gateway resource in Azure for your gateway installation then you can use it to get access to your on premise Azure DevOps by APIs.

Click [Connect to on-premises data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection#create-azure-gateway-resource) for detailed steps.

> 1. In the Azure portal, create or open your logic app in the Logic App
>    Designer.
> 2. Add a connector that supports on-premises connections, for example,
>    SQL Server.
> 3. Select **Connect via on-premises data gateway**.
> 4. Under **Gateway**, from the **Subscription** list, select your Azure
>    subscription that has the gateway resource you want.
> 5. From the **Connection Gateway** list, which shows the available gateway
>    resources in your selected subscription, select the gateway resource
>    that you want. Each gateway resource is linked to a single gateway
>    installation.
> 6. Provide a unique connection name and other required information, which
>    depends on the connection that you want to create.
> 7. When you're done, select Create.
>
> Your gateway connection is now ready for your logic app to use.

Comment: Your answer is for Azure DevOps Services, isn't it? The question is how to connect to Azure DevOps on premise.